# nginx timeout (Centos 7.7 upgrade)

Tags: nginx

This was caused by an upgrade to Centos 7.7

```
systemctl start nginx13.service
```

This blocks, and while blocking nginx is running fine. After 1 minute there is a timeout message. And the service stops.

```
Can't open PID file /var/run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

But the PID file is there. What can cause this trouble?

I tried to change /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to point to somewhere else for the pid file, no luck .It still looks for /var/run/nginx.pid.

Comment: What is the content of your systemd unit? Run `systemctl cat nginx13.service`

Comment: I know you may not using cpanel for nginx, but the workaround in cpanel forum might help. https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/ups-177-service-failures-after-centos-7-7-update.659933/